# How to get an avarage of something from a table using data from another table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this table

```
table A(price) and this table B(name)
```

and i want to get the Avarage price of something from Table A using the name from table B

I tried like this

`select AVG(a.price) from a,b where b.name='something'` but this returns the Avarage of all the items in table A.
I also tried using join like this

`AVG(a.price) from a left join b on b.name='something'` 
but it returns the same thing as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a key in your join. The price in table A for an item must be against a record with a specific key whereby the same key is available in table b with the name. It might be something like below.

```
Select avg(price) from A
Join B on
A.key=B.key
Where B.name=‘something’
```

Then again this depends on your table structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the keys set,The `A.key=B.key` was what i was missing.Thank you very much again